# Error in Python: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, typeerror, nonetype

So I have some code in Python that is supposed to take 3 integers and compare them to each other and then determine which of the three integers are the smallest and largest values. When I run the code, I keep getting the error of:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/sandbox/LargeSmall.py", line 41, in \<module\>
if small_num_three \< small_num_two:
TypeError: '\<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'NoneType'
```

Here is the line where the error occurs:

```py
if small_num_three < small_num_two:
    small_num_three = smallest
else: small_num_two < small_num_three
small_num_two = smallest
```

Here is the full code:

```py
#LargeSmall.py - This program calculates the largest and smallest of three integer values.
# Declare and initialize variables here
largest = None
smallest = None

firstNumber = None
secondNumber = None
thirdNumber = None

# Prompt the user to enter 3 integer values
firstNumber = input("Enter first integer: "  )
secondNumber = input("Enter second integer: "  )
thirdNumber = input("Enter third integer: "  )

# Write assignments, and necessary if else statements here as appropriate
if firstNumber > secondNumber:
    big_num_one = firstNumber
    small_num_one = secondNumber
else: secondNumber > firstNumber
big_num_one = secondNumber
small_num_one = firstNumber

if firstNumber > thirdNumber:
    big_num_two = firstNumber
    small_num_two = thirdNumber
else: thirdNumber > firstNumber
big_num_two = thirdNumber
small_num_two = firstNumber

if secondNumber > thirdNumber:
    big_num_three = secondNumber
    small_num_three = thirdNumber
else: thirdNumber > secondNumber
big_num_three = thirdNumber
small_num_three = secondNumber


if small_num_one < small_num_two:
    small_num_one = smallest
else: small_num_two < small_num_one
small_num_two = smallest

if small_num_three < small_num_two:
   small_num_three = smallest
else: small_num_two < small_num_three
small_num_two = smallest

if small_num_three < small_num_one:
   small_num_three = smallest
else: small_num_one < small_num_three
small_num_one = smallest


if big_num_one > big_num_two:
    big_num_one = largest
else: big_num_two > big_num_one
big_num_two = largest

if big_num_three > big_num_two:
    big_num_three = largest
else: big_num_two > big_num_three
big_num_two = largest

if big_num_three > big_num_one:
    big_num_three = largest
else: big_num_one > big_num_three
big_num_one = largest



print("The largest value is " + str(largest))
print("The smallest value is " + str(smallest))
```

I've seen solutions that say to remove the value of "none" from the initial declared variables, but how would I initialize them and then have the values stored *in* them afterwards if I don't initialize them in that way?

Comment: This is a rather convoluted approach. The codr can be written with 5 variables and 4 simple `if` statements instead. By the way: You are comparing strings because you didn't convert the input to numbers.

Comment: In the 19th line, why do you write `else: secondNumber > firstNumber`? I think you should write `elif secondNumber > firstNumber:` and then indent the next two rows. I think there are lots of mistakes in your code.

Comment: You can remove the none statements. They are initialized by assigning value from `input()` function. Also `input()` function always return a datatype of `str`. you need to convert it to `int` before performing arthimetic comparisons.

Comment: By the way, `min()` and `max()` function accept multiple values.

Comment: Thank you!! I have been using this format of code because my course at the moment said to do it in if and else statements and provided the guidelines for the code. However when I remove the none, it says I have not defined the variable

Comment: Well, as written, this code is not formatted correctly. You cannot put a condition after `else`. Only `elif`, and before the colon. Also statements inside the else body need to be indented

Comment: When I indent the statements inside the else body it says "unexpected indent" as the error

Comment: Convert the input values with `int(input("1st number"))`. Then, you can store the first number and then use if statements to compare with the other two. Do it for the smallest and largest numbers and store the number in the initialized variable to overwrite the initial value you have stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to convert your input to int not str

Like that :

```
firstNumber = int(input("Enter first integer: "))
secondNumber = int(input("Enter second integer: "))
thirdNumber = int(input("Enter third integer: "))
```

Second, you don't need to declare variables with None value cause they will have an input so it's not needed.

This will run your code without errors. But the complexity of the code is too bad cause you have a lot of `if, else` statements.

So if you want here is an optimized version of the code:

```
# Initialize variables
largest = None
smallest = None

# Prompt the user to enter 3 integer values
firstNumber = int(input("Enter first integer: "))
secondNumber = int(input("Enter second integer: "))
thirdNumber = int(input("Enter third integer: "))

# Assign values to largest and smallest variables
if firstNumber >= secondNumber and firstNumber >= thirdNumber:
    largest = firstNumber
elif secondNumber >= firstNumber and secondNumber >= thirdNumber:
    largest = secondNumber
else:
    largest = thirdNumber

if firstNumber <= secondNumber and firstNumber <= thirdNumber:
    smallest = firstNumber
elif secondNumber <= firstNumber and secondNumber <= thirdNumber:
    smallest = secondNumber
else:
    smallest = thirdNumber

# Print the results
print("The largest value is", largest)
print("The smallest value is", smallest)
```

Comment: Cool. I wrote the same code ;)

Comment: Thank you! I ended up still having to use the else if statements (due to how my professor wanted the exact code to look like even though I know there was a more optimal way) but your code made me realize I was typing thirdNumber = largest, instead of largest = thirdNumber which was resulting in the error!!

Answer (score 1):

Decided to reference the if-statement version I have mentioned in my comment:

> You can store the first number and then use if statements to compare the first number with the other two (smallest, then largest). Store the number in the initialized variable to overwrite the value you have initially stored.

```
firstNumber = int(input("Enter first integer: "))
secondNumber = int(input("Enter second integer: "))
thirdNumber = int(input("Enter third integer: "))

smallest = firstNumber
largest = firstNumber

if secondNumber < smallest:
    smallest = secondNumber
elif thirdNumber < smallest:
    smallest = thirdNumber

if secondNumber > largest:
    largest = secondNumber
elif thirdNumber > largest:
    largest = thirdNumber

print("Smallest number:", smallest)
print("Largest number:", largest)
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes the comment earlier definitely helped me with fixing the input so that it takes int instead of a string